# Flutter Overflow Pixel issue

Tags: android, flutter

This is from London App Brewery completed Flutter project "BMI Calculator": https://github.com/londonappbrewery/BMI-Calculator-Flutter-Completed.git

I'm not sure if caused by my outdated android phone or the android screen is too small, but I'm getting `Bottom Overflow Pixels` For example, the top two cards have an error message of `Bottom Overflow by 19 Pixels`, the center card has an error of `Bottom Overflowed by 60 pixels`, and bottom two cards have an error of `Bottom Overflowed by 56 pixels`.

Additionally, if I rotate my phone to 90 degrees, the card image size decreases dramatically, as you can see from the second image.

Please help me fix this.

Thank you

[image]

```dart
 class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage {
    @override   
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
       resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
       appBar: AppBar(
         title: Text('BMI CALCULATOR'),
       ),
       body: Column(
        children: <Widget[
           Expanded(
               child: Row(
             children: <Widget[
               Expanded(
                 child: ReusableCard(
                   colour: colorCode,
                   cardChild: Column(
                     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                     children: <Widget[
                       Icon(
                         FontAwesomeIcons.mars,
                         size: 20.0,
                       ),
                       SizedBox(
                         height: 5.0,
                       ),
                       Text(
                         'MALE',
                         style: TextStyle(
                           fontSize: 10.0,
                           color: Color(0xFF8D8E98),
                         ),
                       )
                     ],
                   ),
                 ),
               )]),),
        ]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your UI takes up too much space for your phone! You have two options to solve this.

Either you wrap your overflowing widgets in a scrolling widget, like `SingleChildScrollView`, this will let you scroll the Widget if it is too large.

Or you calculate the size of the widget based on device size. You can do that by using the `MediaQuery` class:

`MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` Can be used to get device height for instance.
Have a look at this article if you want to go down that path. https://medium.com/tagmalogic/widgets-sizes-relative-to-screen-size-in-flutter-using-mediaquery-3f283afc64d6

Of course you could also just reduce the size of your Widgets so it fits on your device. Thats fine for Tutorial purposes, but if you actually want to publish an App, go with the `MediaQuery`approach.

Good luck!